# XML Changing value of namespace property

Tags: php, xml

I need to change a value of a nested namespace property within a XML document before I submit it to an EPP service.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0 epp-1.0.xsd">
   <command>
     <info>
       <host:info xmlns:host="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:host-1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:host-1.0 host-1.0.xsd">
         <host:name>ns1.example.test.example.com</host:name>
       </host:info>
     </info>
     <clTRID>NORID-14373-1207137695427775</clTRID>
   </command>
 </epp>
```

In the above XML, I need to change the host:name elements value. I am using PHP simplexml_load_string to first modify the values from the XML schema as shown below.

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($fn));
 $xml->command->clTRID = GUID(); // This works perfectly
 $xml->command->info->name = 'somename'; // Does not work :)
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

**Note I am echoing the data for your reference as how to use it**

```
echo $xml->command->info->children('host', true)->info->name;
```

**Total simple code which I tried**

```
$xmls = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0 epp-1.0.xsd">
   <command>
     <info>
       <host:info xmlns:host="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:host-1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:host-1.0 host-1.0.xsd">
         <host:name>ns1.example.test.example.com</host:name>
       </host:info>
     </info>
     <clTRID>NORID-14373-1207137695427775</clTRID>
   </command>
 </epp>';

 $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmls);
 $xml->command->clTRID = 'something'; // This works perfectly
 echo $xml->command->info->children('host', true)->info->name; 

 $xml->command->info->children('host', true)->info->name = 'some new name';
 echo $xml->command->info->children('host', true)->info->name;
```